# The (female) name Freeda amongst Sefardim

Tags: names, women, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, etymology, yiddish

I am under the impression that the name Freeda is a female Yiddish name. For some reason it seems to be very popular amongst the Sephardim. How did this happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its source may be the Arabic name Farida, which means "unique / precious" (as opposed to the Germanic name Frida, which means "peace"). [[link](http://www.sephardicgen.com/databases/SephardicGivenNamesSearchEngine.php?GivenNameSoundex=F630&GivenNameKind=sounds&GivenNameMax=frida&RootNameKind=exact&RootNameMax=&GenderKind=exact&GenderMax=&LanguageKind=exact&LanguageMax=&MeaningKind=exact&MeaningMax=&LocalityFirstFoundKind=exact&LocalityFirstFoundMax=&SourceFirstFoundKind=exact&SourceFirstFoundMax=&DiminutiveKind=exact&DiminutiveMax=&offset=1&pagesize=50)]